# Unable to create the CRON job using the Java code..!

Tags: java, cron

```
String command = "(crontab -l ; echo \"*/1 * * * * /home/Anil/Tutor/test.sh\") |crontab -";    
executeCommand(command);
```

The Execute method :-

```
private static String executeCommand(String command) {
    System.out.println("Command  "+command);

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Error:

> Command  (crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * /home/Anil/Tutor/test.sh") >|crontab -
>
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "(crontab": error=2, No >such file or directory
>
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
>
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
>
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
>
> at Cron_Jobs.Example3.executeCommand(Example3.java:22)
>
> at Cron_Jobs.Example3.main(Example3.java:10)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
>
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:248)
>
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
>
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
>
> ... 5 more

The command will create the job, when I execute it in a command prompt. Now I need to create the job by executing it in java code and getting the error.

Comment: You are attempting to directly execute a shell command string without the shell.  There is no program named `(crontab`. If you want to use shell constructs you must invoke a shell and pass it the command line.

Comment: "(crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * /home/Anil/Tutor/test.sh") |crontab - "  If this command used in Command Prompt works without error and creates the Job, but If I use in java Code I am getting the Error.  How to invoke the Shell and pass command in Java?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?